# Specific mysql_fetch_array sum values of same key

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have following structure of mysql: 
Record looks like that:

```
 id invoice_id position_name qty price_without_tax tax currency
  1     12      Processor I7   2     120.00        23%       €
  2     12      Processor I5   3     80.00         15%       €
  3     12      Processor AMD  2     60.00         15%       €
  4     12      Processor I3   1     60.00          0%       €
```

And I have to sum tax value by the key to get something like that:

```
According to VAT rate | Net    | Vat Amount | Gross

 23%                  | 240.00 | 55.20      | 295.20

 15%                  | 360.00 | 54.00      | 414.00

 0%                   | 60.00  | 0.00       | 60.00

TOTAL                 | 660.00 | 109.20     | 769.20
```

I thought to download records by:

```
$position=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM position where invoice_id = '$id'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($position))
    {
Sum there
    }
```

But really don't know how to sum values of VAT. Could you help me with that?

Comment: vat rate or vat amount ?

Comment: Vat amount per vat rate

Comment: you have already made sum 109.20 or you dont know how to echo it ?

Comment: I don't know how to echo Vat amount according to vat rate, and how to sum that.

Comment: Vat amount is (tax/100 * (price_without_tax * qty)) i.e. 0.23 * (120 * 2) = 55.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's not good to use mysql_fetch_array. Since this extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. More info:
[mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

About your question (using your code)

```
$position=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM position where invoice_id = '$id'");

$products_by_vat = array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($position))
{
    $row["tax"] = str_replace("%", "", $row["tax"]); // as far as I can see tax is a string not a number and has % at the end
    if(!isset($products_by_vat[$row["tax"]])) {
        $products_by_vat[$row["tax"]]["price"] = $products_by_vat[$row["tax"]]["vat_amount"] = 0.0;
    }
    $tmp_price = $row["qty"] * $row["price_without_tax"];
    $products_by_vat[$row["tax"]]["price"] += $tmp_price;
    $products_by_vat[$row["tax"]]["vat_amount"] += $tmp_price * ($row["tax"]/100);
}

echo "VAT % | PRICE | VAT AMOUNT | PRICE WITH VAT \n";

$total_price = $total_vat_amount = 0.0;
foreach($products_by_vat as $vat_percent => $vat_info) {
    $total_price += $vat_info["price"];
    $total_vat_amount += $vat_info["vat_amount"];

    $price_with_vat = $vat_info["price"] + $vat_info["vat_amount"];
    echo "{$vat_percent} | {$vat_info["price"]} | {$vat_info["vat_amount"]} | {$price_with_vat} \n"; 
}
$total_price_with_vat  = $total_price + $total_vat_amount;
echo "TOTAL | {$total_price} | {$total_vat_amount} | {$total_price_with_vat} \n";
```

Considering that price_without_tax is a price per 1 product.

Comment: It's sum amount all Tax's. I would like to sum amount according to vat rate.

Comment: What do you mean with "rates of Tax"?

Comment: I want to calculate amount of each Vat rates. Like in example:      23% | 240.00 | 55.20 | 295.20

Comment: On the code above just `echo $tmp_sum * ($row["tax"]/100));` it will give you 55.20

Comment: That's true, but if I get 2 same tax, your code will don't sum them.

Comment: The question was very unclear, but i believe this version of the code will do the job for you.

Comment: Now it works very well. Thanks you for your attention, and I sorry for my bad english.